# Serializing err.h calls in a mulit-threaded program

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, openmp, stderr

My program uses the `<err.h>` functions (like `warnx(3)`) to emit diagnostics. *Sometimes* multiple threads do the reporting at the same time, resulting in the output lines overlapping.

It is not a big deal, but if there is an easy fix, I'd like to implement it... Is there?

(The threading is all managed by OpenMP.)

Comment: What about using a critical section to avoid this effect? (ie. `#pragma omp critical`

Comment: That's an idea, thank you! There are multiple `warnx`-calls throughout the program -- putting a `#pragma` next to each will be quite invasive. I was hoping for something done through the stdio-mechanism (which all `err(3)` functions use internally)... Something I'd do _once_ before the parallelized loop...

Comment: You can wrap the lock in a function (with the same prototype) and call it. Note that stdio/stderr accesses should already be locked, that being said, regarding the kind of operations done on it, the lock are not guaranteed to cut lines or block of lines the way you want (this is especially true if you do multiple calls to warnx for example).

Comment: I used the method you suggested around the most-frequent calls to `warnx` -- it is an improvement. Make your comments into a proper answer, please, so I can accept it :) You're right about `stderr` already being locked, but a single call to `warnx` has _multiple_ calls to `fprintf` -- and those are intertwined sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to avoid the interleaved printed warnings is to use an OpenMP *critical section*. To do that, one can use the directive `#pragma omp critical` in a wrapping function replacing the `warnx` calls.

Note that stdio/stderr accesses should already be locked, that being said, regarding the kind of operations done on it, the lock are not guaranteed to cut lines or block of lines the way you want. This is especially true if you do multiple calls to `warnx` for example, but also if an implementation of `warnx` use multiple calls to `fprintf` (as you pointed out in the comments).